# How can I create an Entity, add it to my database context, and return its attributes from another Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm pretty new to asp.net and c# and I recently ran into this problem which I can't seem to work around.
Basically, I inherited the IdentityUser class like so, and added my own attributes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("Wallet")]
    public int WalletID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Portfolio")]
    public int PortfolioID { get; set; }
    public virtual Wallet Wallet { get; set; }
    public virtual Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the problem occurs when I try to register using the auto generated register page because the fields `WalletID` and `PorfolioID` are
not initialized. A few things I tried  inside the `Register.cshtml.cs` code for the Identity Account were:

- Creating a new Wallet and Portfolio using :
  `Wallet w = new Wallet(); Portfolio p = new Portfolio();`
  and assigning their id to corresponding attributes inside the `ApplicationUser`. The problem with this is that I don't know how to get the instance of the database context so they are not added to the database and therefore violate the ForeignKey constraint.
- Tried to get instance of  `WalletController` and `PortfolioController`, then call the `Create()` methods  from inside the `Register.cshtml.cs`, but to no avail. I also read that this is bad practice and should be avoided.

Essentially, what I want to do is, when someone registers, create an instance of `Portfolio` and `Wallet`, add them to my database, assign their IDs to corresponding attributes inside the `ApplicationUser` and proceed with the registraton.

What is the best way to solve this?

The auto-generated Register.cshtml.cs:

```
using...
    namespace CryptoSimulation.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public class RegisterModel : PageModel
        {
            private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
            private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
            private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
            private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
    
    
            public RegisterModel(
                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
                ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
                IEmailSender emailSender)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _signInManager = signInManager;
                _logger = logger;
                _emailSender = emailSender;
            }
    
            [BindProperty]
            public InputModel Input { get; set; }
    
            public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    
            public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }
    
            public class InputModel
            {
                [Required]
                [EmailAddress]
                [Display(Name = "Email")]
                public string Email { get; set; }
    
                [Required]
                [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
                [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                [Display(Name = "Password")]
                public string Password { get; set; }
    
                [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
                [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
                public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
            }
    
            public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            }
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
            {
                returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
                ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                     
                    
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
    
                        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                        code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                        var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                            "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                            pageHandler: null,
                            values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                            protocol: Request.Scheme);
    
                        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                            $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");
    
                        if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                        {
                            return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                    }
                }
    
                // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }
```

The auto-generated WalletController (PortfolioController is pretty much the same):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CryptoSimulation.Data;
using CryptoSimulation.Models;

namespace CryptoSimulation.Controllers
{
    public class PortfolioController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public PortfolioController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Portfolio
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Portfolio.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Portfolio/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var portfolio = await _context.Portfolio
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PortfolioID == id);
            if (portfolio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(portfolio);
        }

        // GET: Portfolio/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Portfolio/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PortfolioID")] Portfolio portfolio)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(portfolio);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(portfolio);
        }



        // GET: Portfolio/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var portfolio = await _context.Portfolio.FindAsync(id);
            if (portfolio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(portfolio);
        }

        // POST: Portfolio/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("PortfolioID")] Portfolio portfolio)
        {
            if (id != portfolio.PortfolioID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(portfolio);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!PortfolioExists(portfolio.PortfolioID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(portfolio);
        }

        // GET: Portfolio/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var portfolio = await _context.Portfolio
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PortfolioID == id);
            if (portfolio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(portfolio);
        }

        // POST: Portfolio/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var portfolio = await _context.Portfolio.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Portfolio.Remove(portfolio);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool PortfolioExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Portfolio.Any(e => e.PortfolioID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your controller code look like?

Comment: @Jasen Just did.

Comment: " assigning their id"... Is the id auto-generated by the DB? Then you want to assign the navigation properties, not the ids. And you want to do that before calling `.CreateAsync`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Doing this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but my guess. I cannot comment on SO yet. My guess is that the code is aware of your foreign keys but the DB is not. You can add migration and update database.

Adding migration in Package Manager in VS using `add-migration` command will generate all changes. `update database` will actually apply the changes to the DB. You can look at the `Up()` method in the generated migration to see if the foreign keys are reflected properly

Documentation for migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli